# How to update a column through a column variable?

Tags: sql-update, updates, dolphindb

I want to update a column through a specific column variable. For example, I want to create a SQL `update` statement `update t1 set col1 = col1 * 3`, where *t1* is a table and *col1* is a column name. To make the statement work, a column object is needed, so I need to generate a column object by name. Does anyone know how to do this? If so, can you share some best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Metaprogramming. The function `sqlCol` is a good choice.

For example, for the following update job *t.price = t.price * 3*,

where *t* is a table and *price* is a column, you can use the following 3 ways:

```
t1=table(`A`A`B`B as symbol, 2021.04.15 2021.04.16 2021.04.15 2021.04.16 as date, 12 13 21 22 as price)
col="price"
t1[col]=t1[col]*3  //Method 1
t1[col]=expr(sqlCol(col),*,3)  //Method 2
sqlUpdate("t1",sqlColAlias(expr(sqlCol(col),*,3),col)).eval()  //Method 3
```

Note:  Method 1 and Method 2 are only applicable to in-memory tables.